# Can't seem to get Wix to install driver

Tags: windows, wix, driver, dpinst

I followed the tutorial here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/driver-install-with-wix.aspx but it just doesn't seem to want to work - the `DPInst` exe never actually seems to run? All the files are being laid-down correctly - I even noticed that in the tutorial they missed a quote.

My custom action looks like this:

```
<CustomAction Id='Install_M2_Driver'
              Execute='deferred' Directory='DRIVER_ROOT'
              ExeCommand='"[dirDpInst]DPInst.exe" /SA /PATH "[dirM2]"'
              Return='ignore' />
```

I even tried replacing the `DPInst.exe` with a simple exe that echoed the arguments back to me, everything looks good, if I actually run the command from the command-line while the echo message box was up it would bring up the DPInst install GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it, need to turn impersonate off:

```
<CustomAction Id='Install_M2_Driver'
              Execute='deferred'
              Directory='DRIVER_ROOT'
              Impersonate='no'
              ExeCommand='"[dirDpInst]DPInst.exe" /SA /PATH \"[dirM2]\"'
              Return='ignore' />
```