# How to install drivers using pnputil with Burn (Wix)

Tags: wix, driver, bootstrapper, burn

I am working with Wix Boostrapper to install some packages on Windows 10 (Wix Toolset v3.11). Everything is fine with my MSIs and EXEs. However, I have to install a driver using the following command (in a .cmd file):

```
pnputil /add-driver myDriver.inf /install
```

So I used the following line inside my bundle:

```xml
<ExePackage Id="driver" SourceFile="myPath\install.cmd" Compressed="yes" Vital="yes" />
```

Unfortunately, I have a `0x80070001 incorrect function` error. Below is a part of the logfile:

```
[4C38:4A18][2019-04-02T11:11:36]e000: Error 0x80070001: Process returned error: 0x1
[4C38:4A18][2019-04-02T11:11:36]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to execute EXE package.
[4F24:4BC8][2019-04-02T11:11:36]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[4F24:4BC8][2019-04-02T11:11:36]i319: Applied execute package: driver, result: 0x80070001, restart: None
[4F24:4BC8][2019-04-02T11:11:36]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to execute EXE package.
```

I tested if I could read the file with basic commands (`mkdir`...) and it worked. I guess the problem is that Window or Wix doesn't like the use of  `pnputil` but I don't know what I can do/check.

I might create an MSI to install my driver but I'm not sure this is the most appropriate way.

Any idea?

Comment: Having a look. [Meanwhile, maybe check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035367/how-do-i-install-drivers-using-burn-and-dpinst-after-msi-installation).

Comment: Using `DPinst.exe` you should be able to install any signed driver - for now ([driver installation is changing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51845307/129130)). I suppose you could add `DPinst.exe` as a support file. I have never tried. I suppose you could use a self-extracting exe with dpinst.exe embedded to install as well - making it a regular exepackage entry.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Also, before reading your answer, I tried to create an msi with Wix. I added my files in a folder then I run my  command in a custom Action. It works but it wasn't really elegant.