# Avoiding multiple UAC prompts during MSI installation

Tags: wix, installation, uac

We have a msi installer which we have created using the wix installer. This installer also includes certain device drivers that need to be installed. We install the device drivers via a custom action. This custom action executes a .bat file that contains the utility dpinst64 to install the driver package. I have used the following option with the dpinst64

```
@if /I "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "AMD64" (
  rem echo Installing driver from 64-bit installer on Windows 7
rem  dpinst64.exe /SW /S /PATH W7
  dpinst64.exe /q /se /PATH W7
) else if /I "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "X86" (
    rem echo Installing driver from 32-bit installer on Windows 7
    dpinst32.exe /q  /se /PATH W7
  )
)
```

What happens is when the user double clicks on the msi, the user gets a prompt to enter his / her credentials. After this installation proceeds OK. When the time comes to install the drivers, the user is again prompted with the credential window. I would like to know how can I avoid this coming again. I was thinking since I have already provided my credentials, this should remain for the rest of the session. However this seems to be not the case.

Answer (score 2):

***Batch Files Considered Harmful***: Batch files must be avoided at all cost for MSI deployment. They are clunky, obsolete and almost without error handling and generally feature no rollback.

***WiX Driver Element***: Recommend you try to use the [**WiX Driver Element**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/difxapp/driver.html) instead. It uses the DIFx framework under the hood - as far as I know. [A small, practical example found on github.com](https://github.com/tixsys/esteid/blob/a0be3c31a0390f68f042127f0498e0900d0304a5/packages/windows/trunk/minidriver.wxs).

***Previous Answer***: [Maybe see this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815839/customaction-driverpackageinstall-failing-with-0x80030005/52820791#52820791) for more on the **`difx:Driver`** construct:

```
<Component>
   <File ... /> 
   <difx:Driver ... />
</Component>
```

---

***Links***:

- **https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware**
- **[WiX silent install unable to launch built in .EXE: WiX v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832177/wix-silent-install-unable-to-launch-built-in-exe-wix-v3/51845307#51845307)**
- [WiX silent install unable to launch built in .EXE: WiX v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832177/wix-silent-install-unable-to-launch-built-in-exe-wix-v3/51845307#51845307)
- [Can't seem to get Wix to install driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820598/cant-seem-to-get-wix-to-install-driver)